# JQuery: How to make 3D Joystick image with bending effects?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

i am making an app where i need 3d joystick image so that user can swipe on it and image will bend in swipped direction.

For swipe down or for swipe up events what css or animation effect i should give to make image moving downside or upside ??

I don't know the best way to do it. I am trying this code :-

```
 <div style="width:220px;height:220px;background-color:black;display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle; text-align:center" id="joy_div">
        <img id="joystick" src="joystick.png" >
</div>

<script>
$("#joy_div").rotate({ 
    bind: 
    { 
        swipeleft : function() { 
            $("#joystick").rotate({animateTo:-50});
        },
        swiperight : function() { 
            $("#joystick").rotate({animateTo:50});
        },
        swipeup : function(){
            alert('up');
        },
        swipedown : function(){
            alert('down');
        },
        swipeend : function(){
            $("#joystick").rotate({animateTo:0});
        }
    }); 
</script>
```

I appreciate any guidance.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: for swipedown or for swipeup events what css or animation effect i should give to make image moving downside or upside

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest you to use CSS `transform` and `perspective` to do this.

In the example below, I've demonstrated this using buttons for swipeLeft, swipeRight, swipeUp and swipeDown events.

```js
$(".tilt").click(function() {
  $('#joystick').removeAttr('class');
  $('#joystick').addClass($(this).attr('id'));
});
```

```css
#joy_div {
  perspective: 500px;
}
button {
  margin: 10px 0 0 0;
}
.left, .right, .down, .up, .reset {
  transition: transform 0.5s ease;
  transform-origin: 50% 50%;
}
.left {
  transform: rotateY(-40deg);
}
.right {
  transform: rotateY(40deg);
}
.up {
  transform: rotateX(-40deg);
}
.down {
  transform: rotateX(40deg);
}
.reset {
  transform: rotateX(0) rotateY(0);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div style="width:250px;height:160px;display:table-cell; vertical-align:middle; text-align:center" id="joy_div">
  <img id="joystick" width="250" height="160" src="http://help.robotc.net/WebHelpArduino/scr/TETRIX_MATRIX_New/NXT_Using_Joysticks_files/Joystick_front.gif" />
</div>
<button class="tilt" id="left">swipeleft</button>
<button class="tilt" id="right">swiperight</button>
<button class="tilt" id="up">swipeup</button>
<button class="tilt" id="down">swipedown</button>
<button class="tilt" id="reset">Reset</button>
```

Comment: hi , i am using this code in my phonegap app.It works fine on web and android version less than 4.4.On android 4.4 and on iphone these properties are not working.Do you have any idea why it is happening.

Answer (score 2):

Something like this? (although this is a very crude design, and not fully implemented)

```js
$('#left').click(function(){
  $('.stick').removeClass("right").toggleClass("left");
});
$('#right').click(function(){
  $('.stick').removeClass("left").toggleClass("right");
});
```

```css
.wrapper{
  width:300px;
  height:300px;
  background:gray;
  }

.stick{
  height:30px;
  width:30px;
  border-radius:50%;
  background:red;
  margin:0 auto;
  position:relative;
  z-index:5;
}

.stick:after{
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  height:200px;
  width:20px;
  background:red;
  bottom:-180px;
  left:15%;
  z-index:2;
  }

.joy{
  
  height:30px;
  width:100%;
  background:darkgray;
  margin-top:170px;
  position:relative;
  z-index:20;
  }

.left{
  transform:rotate(-20deg);
  left:-50px;
  }

.right{
  transform:rotate(20deg);
  left:50px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
   <div class="stick"></div>
  <div class="joy"></div>

</div>

<button id="left">left</button>
<button id="right">right</button>
```

As for the 'up' and 'down' motions, you may want to look into the 3d perspective css property.

---

If you were able to use SCSS, you may want to look at:

- [This joystick implementation](http://codepen.io/hugosocie/pen/DelFm)

If not, something like [this](http://codepen.io/highfestiva/pen/BfEhC) I think would also be beneficial to see

## Incredible Example ~[SOURCE](http://codepen.io/abergin/pen/DjCce) NOT MADE BY ME

---

```css
* {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

html , body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%:
    overflow: hidden;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0%;
    left: 0%;
}

html {
    background-color: rgba(240,255,255,1);    
}

#letter {
    font-size: 120px;
    font-family: Helvetica;
    font-weight: Bold;
    color: rgba(18,22,26,0.7);
    width: 120px;
    height: 120px;
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 120px;
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -60px;
    margin-left: -60px;
    opacity: 1;
    z-index: -1;
}

#description {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 10px;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 100;
    font-family: Helvetica;
    font-weight: 200;
    color: rgba(18,22,26,0.7);
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 11px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
}

#animation {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    z-index: 1;
}

.base {
    width: 170px;
    height: 30px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -85px;
    margin-top: 95px;
    background-color: rgba(123,126,129,1);
    z-index: -1;
}

.base:after {
    border-bottom: 40px solid rgba(193,196,199,1);
    border-right: 20px solid transparent;
    border-left: 20px solid transparent;
    position: absolute;
    top: -85px;
    left: 0px;
    width: 130px;
    height: 45px;
    content: "";
}

.button {
    width: 16px;
    height: 35px;
    background-color: rgba(23,26,29,0.5);
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    -webkit-transform-origin: center bottom;
    transform-origin: center bottom;
    -webkit-transform: scale( 1 , 0.35 );
    -moz-transform: scale( 1 , 0.35 );
    -ms-transform: scale( 1 , 0.35 );
    -o-transform: scale( 1 , 0.35 );
    transform: scale( 1 , 0.35 );
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.button:after {
    content: "";
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgba(255,115,110,1);
    border-radius: 20px;
}

#animation .button:nth-of-type(1) {
    margin-top: 50px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    animation: baseButton 6s ease 0s infinite alternate none;
 -webkit-animation: baseButton 6s ease 0s infinite alternate none;
}

#animation .button:nth-of-type(2) {
    margin-top: 55px;
    margin-left: 50px;
    animation: baseButton 6.5s ease 2s infinite alternate none;
 -webkit-animation: baseButton 6.5s ease 2s infinite alternate none;
}

.stick {
    background-color: rgba(123,126,129,1);
    width: 22px;
    height: 100px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -11px;
    margin-top: -65px;
    z-index: 10;
    -webkit-transform-origin: center 180px;
    transform-origin: center 180px;
    animation: stick 7s ease-in-out 0s infinite alternate none;
 -webkit-animation: stick 7s ease-in-out 0s infinite alternate none;
}

.stick:after {
    -webkit-transform: scale( 1 , 0.25 );
    -moz-transform: scale( 1 , 0.25 );
    -ms-transform: scale( 1 , 0.25 );
    -o-transform: scale( 1 , 0.25 );
    transform: scale( 1 , 0.25 );
    background-color: rgba(193,196,199,1);
    border-radius: 34px;
    position: absolute;
    top: -11px;
    left: 0;
    width: 22px;
    height: 22px;
    content: "";
}

.stick:before {
    -webkit-transform: scale( 1 , 0.35 );
    -moz-transform: scale( 1 , 0.35 );
    -ms-transform: scale( 1 , 0.35 );
    -o-transform: scale( 1 , 0.35 );
    transform: scale( 1 , 0.35 );
    background-color: rgba(123,126,129,1);
    border-radius: 34px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 90px;
    left: 0;
    width: 22px;
    height: 22px;
    content: "";
}

.stick .topButton {
    width: 16px;
    height: 35px;
    background-color: rgba(103,106,109,1);
    position: absolute;
    top: 0%;
    left: 0%;
    -webkit-transform-origin: center bottom;
    transform-origin: center bottom;
    -webkit-transform: scale( 1 , 0.25 );
    -moz-transform: scale( 1 , 0.25 );
    -ms-transform: scale( 1 , 0.25 );
    -o-transform: scale( 1 , 0.25 );
    transform: scale( 1 , 0.25 );
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin-left: 3px;
    margin-top: -34px;
    z-index: 20;
    animation: baseButton 3.5s ease -2s infinite alternate forwards;
 -webkit-animation: baseButton 3.5s ease -2s infinite alternate forwards;
}

.stick .topButton:after {
    content: "";
    width: 16px;
    height: 16px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    background-color: rgba(255,115,110,1);
    border-radius: 20px;
}

.stick .bottom {
    -webkit-transform: scale( 1 , 0.55 );
    -moz-transform: scale( 1 , 0.55 );
    -ms-transform: scale( 1 , 0.55 );
    -o-transform: scale( 1 , 0.55 );
    transform: scale( 1 , 0.55 );
    width: 16px;
    height: 35px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -25px;
    left: 3px;
    z-index: -1;
    background-color: rgba(83,86,89,1);
}

.stick .support {
    width: 40px;
    height: 40px;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: -41px;
    left: -9px;
    background-color: rgba(48,50,54,1);
    border-radius: 80px;
    -webkit-transform: scale( 1 , 0.45 );
    -moz-transform: scale( 1 , 0.45 );
    -ms-transform: scale( 1 , 0.45 );
    -o-transform: scale( 1 , 0.45 );
    transform: scale( 1 , 0.45 );
    z-index: -5;
}

.rubber {
    position: absolute;
    width: 80px;
    height: 80px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-left: -40px;
    margin-top: 25px;
    background-color: rgba(38,42,46,1);
    border-radius: 80px;
    -webkit-transform: scale( 1 , 0.35 );
    -moz-transform: scale( 1 , 0.35 );
    -ms-transform: scale( 1 , 0.35 );
    -o-transform: scale( 1 , 0.35 );
    transform: scale( 1 , 0.35 );
    z-index: 1;
}

.cord {
    border-top: 3px solid rgba(38,42,46,1);
    border-left: 3px solid rgba(38,42,46,1);
    border-top-left-radius: 40px;
    width: 30%;
    height: 20px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 80px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 20%;
    z-index: -20;
}

.wallcord {
    border-bottom: 3px solid rgba(38,42,46,1);
    border-right: 3px solid rgba(38,42,46,1);
    border-bottom-right-radius: 40px;
    width: 20%;
    height: 60px;
    position: absolute;
    margin-top: 100px;
    top: 50%;
    left: 0%;
    z-index: -20;
}

@keyframes baseButton {
 64% { -webkit-transform: scale( 1 , 0.35 ); -moz-transform: scale( 1 , 0.35 ); -ms-transform: scale( 1 , 0.35 ); -o-transform: scale( 1 , 0.35 ); transform: scale( 1 , 0.35 );} 
 62% { -webkit-transform: scale( 1 , 0.15 ); -moz-transform: scale( 1 , 0.15 ); -ms-transform: scale( 1 , 0.15 ); -o-transform: scale( 1 , 0.15 ); transform: scale( 1 , 0.15 );} 
 60% { -webkit-transform: scale( 1 , 0.35 ); -moz-transform: scale( 1 , 0.35 ); -ms-transform: scale( 1 , 0.35 ); -o-transform: scale( 1 , 0.35 ); transform: scale( 1 , 0.35 );} 
 100% { -webkit-transform: scale( 1 , 0.15 ); -moz-transform: scale( 1 , 0.15 ); -ms-transform: scale( 1 , 0.15 ); -o-transform: scale( 1 , 0.15 ); transform: scale( 1 , 0.15 );} 
 18% { -webkit-transform: scale( 1 , 0.35 ); -moz-transform: scale( 1 , 0.35 ); -ms-transform: scale( 1 , 0.35 ); -o-transform: scale( 1 , 0.35 ); transform: scale( 1 , 0.35 );} 
 16% { -webkit-transform: scale( 1 , 0.15 ); -moz-transform: scale( 1 , 0.15 ); -ms-transform: scale( 1 , 0.15 ); -o-transform: scale( 1 , 0.15 ); transform: scale( 1 , 0.15 );} 
 0% { -webkit-transform: scale( 1 , 0.35 ); -moz-transform: scale( 1 , 0.35 ); -ms-transform: scale( 1 , 0.35 ); -o-transform: scale( 1 , 0.35 ); transform: scale( 1 , 0.35 );} 
 98% { -webkit-transform: scale( 1 , 0.35 ); -moz-transform: scale( 1 , 0.35 ); -ms-transform: scale( 1 , 0.35 ); -o-transform: scale( 1 , 0.35 ); transform: scale( 1 , 0.35 );} 
 14% { -webkit-transform: scale( 1 , 0.35 ); -moz-transform: scale( 1 , 0.35 ); -ms-transform: scale( 1 , 0.35 ); -o-transform: scale( 1 , 0.35 ); transform: scale( 1 , 0.35 );} 
 10% { -webkit-transform: scale( 1 , 0.35 ); -moz-transform: scale( 1 , 0.35 ); -ms-transform: scale( 1 , 0.35 ); -o-transform: scale( 1 , 0.35 ); transform: scale( 1 , 0.35 );} 
 12% { -webkit-transform: scale( 1 , 0.15 ); -moz-transform: scale( 1 , 0.15 ); -ms-transform: scale( 1 , 0.15 ); -o-transform: scale( 1 , 0.15 ); transform: scale( 1 , 0.15 );} 
}

@-webkit-keyframes baseButton {
 64% { -webkit-transform: scale( 1 , 0.35 ); -moz-transform: scale( 1 , 0.35 ); -ms-transform: scale( 1 , 0.35 ); -o-transform: scale( 1 , 0.35 ); transform: scale( 1 , 0.35 );} 
 62% { -webkit-transform: scale( 1 , 0.15 ); -moz-transform: scale( 1 , 0.15 ); -ms-transform: scale( 1 , 0.15 ); -o-transform: scale( 1 , 0.15 ); transform: scale( 1 , 0.15 );} 
 60% { -webkit-transform: scale( 1 , 0.35 ); -moz-transform: scale( 1 , 0.35 ); -ms-transform: scale( 1 , 0.35 ); -o-transform: scale( 1 , 0.35 ); transform: scale( 1 , 0.35 );} 
 100% { -webkit-transform: scale( 1 , 0.15 ); -moz-transform: scale( 1 , 0.15 ); -ms-transform: scale( 1 , 0.15 ); -o-transform: scale( 1 , 0.15 ); transform: scale( 1 , 0.15 );} 
 18% { -webkit-transform: scale( 1 , 0.35 ); -moz-transform: scale( 1 , 0.35 ); -ms-transform: scale( 1 , 0.35 ); -o-transform: scale( 1 , 0.35 ); transform: scale( 1 , 0.35 );} 
 16% { -webkit-transform: scale( 1 , 0.15 ); -moz-transform: scale( 1 , 0.15 ); -ms-transform: scale( 1 , 0.15 ); -o-transform: scale( 1 , 0.15 ); transform: scale( 1 , 0.15 );} 
 0% { -webkit-transform: scale( 1 , 0.35 ); -moz-transform: scale( 1 , 0.35 ); -ms-transform: scale( 1 , 0.35 ); -o-transform: scale( 1 , 0.35 ); transform: scale( 1 , 0.35 );} 
 98% { -webkit-transform: scale( 1 , 0.35 ); -moz-transform: scale( 1 , 0.35 ); -ms-transform: scale( 1 , 0.35 ); -o-transform: scale( 1 , 0.35 ); transform: scale( 1 , 0.35 );} 
 14% { -webkit-transform: scale( 1 , 0.35 ); -moz-transform: scale( 1 , 0.35 ); -ms-transform: scale( 1 , 0.35 ); -o-transform: scale( 1 , 0.35 ); transform: scale( 1 , 0.35 );} 
 10% { -webkit-transform: scale( 1 , 0.35 ); -moz-transform: scale( 1 , 0.35 ); -ms-transform: scale( 1 , 0.35 ); -o-transform: scale( 1 , 0.35 ); transform: scale( 1 , 0.35 );} 
 12% { -webkit-transform: scale( 1 , 0.15 ); -moz-transform: scale( 1 , 0.15 ); -ms-transform: scale( 1 , 0.15 ); -o-transform: scale( 1 , 0.15 ); transform: scale( 1 , 0.15 );} 
}

@keyframes stick {
 5% { -webkit-transform: rotate( 20deg ); -moz-transform: rotate( 20deg ); -ms-transform: rotate( 20deg ); -o-transform: rotate( 20deg ); transform: rotate( 20deg );} 
 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate( -5deg ); -moz-transform: rotate( -5deg ); -ms-transform: rotate( -5deg ); -o-transform: rotate( -5deg ); transform: rotate( -5deg );} 
 97% { -webkit-transform: rotate( 20deg ); -moz-transform: rotate( 20deg ); -ms-transform: rotate( 20deg ); -o-transform: rotate( 20deg ); transform: rotate( 20deg );} 
 94% { -webkit-transform: rotate( 0deg ); -moz-transform: rotate( 0deg ); -ms-transform: rotate( 0deg ); -o-transform: rotate( 0deg ); transform: rotate( 0deg );} 
 87% { -webkit-transform: rotate( -5deg ); -moz-transform: rotate( -5deg ); -ms-transform: rotate( -5deg ); -o-transform: rotate( -5deg ); transform: rotate( -5deg );} 
 84% { -webkit-transform: rotate( 20deg ); -moz-transform: rotate( 20deg ); -ms-transform: rotate( 20deg ); -o-transform: rotate( 20deg ); transform: rotate( 20deg );} 
 82% { -webkit-transform: rotate( 5deg ); -moz-transform: rotate( 5deg ); -ms-transform: rotate( 5deg ); -o-transform: rotate( 5deg ); transform: rotate( 5deg );} 
 74% { -webkit-transform: rotate( 5deg ); -moz-transform: rotate( 5deg ); -ms-transform: rotate( 5deg ); -o-transform: rotate( 5deg ); transform: rotate( 5deg );} 
 68% { -webkit-transform: rotate( -20deg ); -moz-transform: rotate( -20deg ); -ms-transform: rotate( -20deg ); -o-transform: rotate( -20deg ); transform: rotate( -20deg );} 
 65% { -webkit-transform: rotate( 0deg ); -moz-transform: rotate( 0deg ); -ms-transform: rotate( 0deg ); -o-transform: rotate( 0deg ); transform: rotate( 0deg );} 
 53% { -webkit-transform: rotate( 6deg ); -moz-transform: rotate( 6deg ); -ms-transform: rotate( 6deg ); -o-transform: rotate( 6deg ); transform: rotate( 6deg );} 
 50% { -webkit-transform: rotate( 10deg ); -moz-transform: rotate( 10deg ); -ms-transform: rotate( 10deg ); -o-transform: rotate( 10deg ); transform: rotate( 10deg );} 
 48% { -webkit-transform: rotate( -5deg ); -moz-transform: rotate( -5deg ); -ms-transform: rotate( -5deg ); -o-transform: rotate( -5deg ); transform: rotate( -5deg );} 
 47% { -webkit-transform: rotate( 0deg ); -moz-transform: rotate( 0deg ); -ms-transform: rotate( 0deg ); -o-transform: rotate( 0deg ); transform: rotate( 0deg );} 
 42% { -webkit-transform: rotate( -15deg ); -moz-transform: rotate( -15deg ); -ms-transform: rotate( -15deg ); -o-transform: rotate( -15deg ); transform: rotate( -15deg );} 
 40% { -webkit-transform: rotate( 0deg ); -moz-transform: rotate( 0deg ); -ms-transform: rotate( 0deg ); -o-transform: rotate( 0deg ); transform: rotate( 0deg );} 
 33% { -webkit-transform: rotate( 0deg ); -moz-transform: rotate( 0deg ); -ms-transform: rotate( 0deg ); -o-transform: rotate( 0deg ); transform: rotate( 0deg );} 
 22% { -webkit-transform: rotate( 10deg ); -moz-transform: rotate( 10deg ); -ms-transform: rotate( 10deg ); -o-transform: rotate( 10deg ); transform: rotate( 10deg );} 
 17% { -webkit-transform: rotate( 0deg ); -moz-transform: rotate( 0deg ); -ms-transform: rotate( 0deg ); -o-transform: rotate( 0deg ); transform: rotate( 0deg );} 
 0% { -webkit-transform: rotate( -5deg ); -moz-transform: rotate( -5deg ); -ms-transform: rotate( -5deg ); -o-transform: rotate( -5deg ); transform: rotate( -5deg );} 
}

@-webkit-keyframes stick {
 5% { -webkit-transform: rotate( 20deg ); -moz-transform: rotate( 20deg ); -ms-transform: rotate( 20deg ); -o-transform: rotate( 20deg ); transform: rotate( 20deg );} 
 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate( -5deg ); -moz-transform: rotate( -5deg ); -ms-transform: rotate( -5deg ); -o-transform: rotate( -5deg ); transform: rotate( -5deg );} 
 97% { -webkit-transform: rotate( 20deg ); -moz-transform: rotate( 20deg ); -ms-transform: rotate( 20deg ); -o-transform: rotate( 20deg ); transform: rotate( 20deg );} 
 94% { -webkit-transform: rotate( 0deg ); -moz-transform: rotate( 0deg ); -ms-transform: rotate( 0deg ); -o-transform: rotate( 0deg ); transform: rotate( 0deg );} 
 87% { -webkit-transform: rotate( -5deg ); -moz-transform: rotate( -5deg ); -ms-transform: rotate( -5deg ); -o-transform: rotate( -5deg ); transform: rotate( -5deg );} 
 84% { -webkit-transform: rotate( 20deg ); -moz-transform: rotate( 20deg ); -ms-transform: rotate( 20deg ); -o-transform: rotate( 20deg ); transform: rotate( 20deg );} 
 82% { -webkit-transform: rotate( 5deg ); -moz-transform: rotate( 5deg ); -ms-transform: rotate( 5deg ); -o-transform: rotate( 5deg ); transform: rotate( 5deg );} 
 74% { -webkit-transform: rotate( 5deg ); -moz-transform: rotate( 5deg ); -ms-transform: rotate( 5deg ); -o-transform: rotate( 5deg ); transform: rotate( 5deg );} 
 68% { -webkit-transform: rotate( -20deg ); -moz-transform: rotate( -20deg ); -ms-transform: rotate( -20deg ); -o-transform: rotate( -20deg ); transform: rotate( -20deg );} 
 65% { -webkit-transform: rotate( 0deg ); -moz-transform: rotate( 0deg ); -ms-transform: rotate( 0deg ); -o-transform: rotate( 0deg ); transform: rotate( 0deg );} 
 53% { -webkit-transform: rotate( 6deg ); -moz-transform: rotate( 6deg ); -ms-transform: rotate( 6deg ); -o-transform: rotate( 6deg ); transform: rotate( 6deg );} 
 50% { -webkit-transform: rotate( 10deg ); -moz-transform: rotate( 10deg ); -ms-transform: rotate( 10deg ); -o-transform: rotate( 10deg ); transform: rotate( 10deg );} 
 48% { -webkit-transform: rotate( -5deg ); -moz-transform: rotate( -5deg ); -ms-transform: rotate( -5deg ); -o-transform: rotate( -5deg ); transform: rotate( -5deg );} 
 47% { -webkit-transform: rotate( 0deg ); -moz-transform: rotate( 0deg ); -ms-transform: rotate( 0deg ); -o-transform: rotate( 0deg ); transform: rotate( 0deg );} 
 42% { -webkit-transform: rotate( -15deg ); -moz-transform: rotate( -15deg ); -ms-transform: rotate( -15deg ); -o-transform: rotate( -15deg ); transform: rotate( -15deg );} 
 40% { -webkit-transform: rotate( 0deg ); -moz-transform: rotate( 0deg ); -ms-transform: rotate( 0deg ); -o-transform: rotate( 0deg ); transform: rotate( 0deg );} 
 33% { -webkit-transform: rotate( 0deg ); -moz-transform: rotate( 0deg ); -ms-transform: rotate( 0deg ); -o-transform: rotate( 0deg ); transform: rotate( 0deg );} 
 22% { -webkit-transform: rotate( 10deg ); -moz-transform: rotate( 10deg ); -ms-transform: rotate( 10deg ); -o-transform: rotate( 10deg ); transform: rotate( 10deg );} 
 17% { -webkit-transform: rotate( 0deg ); -moz-transform: rotate( 0deg ); -ms-transform: rotate( 0deg ); -o-transform: rotate( 0deg ); transform: rotate( 0deg );} 
 0% { -webkit-transform: rotate( -5deg ); -moz-transform: rotate( -5deg ); -ms-transform: rotate( -5deg ); -o-transform: rotate( -5deg ); transform: rotate( -5deg );} 
}
```

```html
<div id="letter">J</div>
<div id="description">is for Joystick</div>

<div id="animation">
    <div class="button"></div>
    <div class="button"></div>
    <div class="stick">
        <div class="topButton"></div>
        <div class="bottom"></div>
        <div class="support"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="rubber"></div>
    <div class="base"></div>
    <div class="cord"></div>
    <div class="wallcord"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks, my code is able to do what you are doing right now.I just want to move my image downside and upside.

Comment: @varun - Well, If you were looking for a 2D effect, you should take off **"3D"** from your title.

Comment: @varun: What do you mean by "downside" and "upside"?

Comment: @ jbutler483 , i need 3d effect and my mean with "downside" and "upside" is same as is shown in the above answer having keys "swipeUp" and "swipeDown"

Comment: sorry I think you changed your code.. let me check it first an thanks

Comment: The link to [CodePen](http://codepen.io/hugosocie/pen/DelFm) is pretty cool. +1 :)